# Why doesn't this association load (active model serializers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

This gem is literally one of the most frustrating things I've ever worked with. I really regret using it.

How come my association won't load, even though it's defined on the models and everything properly.

```
class Units::ShowSerializer < UnitSerializer

  has_one :tenant do
    object.user
  end

  has_many :invoices do
    object.invoices
  end

  class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :created_at
  end

  class InvoiceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :generated_at, :due_at

    has_one :payment
  end

end
```

The property in question is `has_one :payment`

No matter how I define it, it just doesn't call that property.

Comment: What is the desired module nesting? - Why are you declaring `UserSerializer` and `InvoiceSerializer` inside the definition for  `Units::ShowSerializer`? Do you even know if your serializer is being used at all?

Comment: It's not being used. If I move the declaration up above, then it gets used but it ignores all the attributes inside it. All this seems to work fine if its 1 layer deep, but hte moment i nest a 2nd item everything breaks. I'm doing it because thats what the docs say to override a serializer for a particular case

Comment: http://blog.honeybadger.io/avoid-these-traps-when-nesting-ruby-modules/